# Smart pointer: runtime crash in VS 9 running WinXP-Sp3

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, tr1

I am getting run time crash in the following piece of code and not able to debug also. Please review and let me know what's going on.

```
// CppConsole.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
    class Test : public std::tr1::enable_shared_from_this<Test>
    {
    public:
        Test():x(0),y(0),z(0){};
        int x;
        float y;
        double z;
    };
```

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<Test> t1(new Test);
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<Test> t2 = t1->shared_from_this();
    return 0;
}
```

I have include all the headers and the program is compiling fine. This is the error i am getting:

> CppConsole.exe - Entry Point Not Found The procedure entry point
>   ?_Xweak@tr1@std@@YAXXZ could not be located in the dynamic link
>   library MSVCP90D.dll

If I comment out this line

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr t2 = t1->shared_from_this();
```

the program runs without crashing.

**Update: Question can be closed for now. I will try to install VS feature pack and see weather the program executes without any crashes.**

Comment: You are missing template argument lists for your `shared_ptr` objects.  Even so, there is something odd going on here.  I don't see anything blatantly wrong with this, and if I add a `#include <memory>` and fix the declarations, I have no issues with this code under VC10 (there _could_ be an issue in VC9, which a you are using, but that would be unusual.)  What settings are you using to compile this project?  If you just compile this .cpp file on the Visual Studio command line (`cl test.cpp` or whatever the file is named), what happens?

Comment: I am using VC9 running on WinXP SP3. I have included all the headers and compilation is not an issue. As far what i understand for creating an instance of shared pointer I don't need a template argument list. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not. A `shared_ptr` *of what*? That's what the template is for. Post your real exact code.

Comment: This is the real exact code that I am trying to understand the concepts of shared pointer and enable_shared_from_this. Please be noted that the creating the instance of t1 pointer never fails, its only when I try to create the instance t2 using the call t1->shared_from_this() the program crashes.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I'd like to see the exact, beginning to end, .cpp file that compiles without a template argument list for `shared_ptr`.  I am fascinated that that would work.

Comment: @James: I have now updated full piece of code. Only 1 cpp file console application.

Comment: @James: I am sorry. Actually the code has template argument list. My bad I am not well versed in html hence the code missed the argument. It is the exact piece of code that compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Googled it (The procedure entry point ?_Xweak),found this : http://blog.nilretain.org/

EDIT : I Build and Run it successfully on my msvc 2008 on xp-sp3 ,which has later version of msvcp90d.dll.
Maybe you can download and install the latest redist-version of msvc90 and rebuild.

EDIT: your dependencies says something is missing. check this out :

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090623140325AAInugo

Comment: Thanks Edwin. i don't have VS service pack installed. But following your link i compiled using the macro **_BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION** but now it complains about **application configuration being incorrect**. I can't make heads or tails out of it. This piece of code is actually valid and can be found in MSDN site.

Comment: @John M: too bad ,it didn't work. Have Googled it. I got 132 results with the search I mentioned. I thought that the one I quoted was a general solution. But i was wrong.

Comment: @John M: followin the link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc664727.aspx ,maybe you must define it as **#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION 1**

Comment: will install VS feature pack and see what happens.

Comment: Hey guys, just FYI my blog post you linked to lives here now: http://devjustinian.com/2009/12/manifest-gotchas.html  (in case it scrolls off the page) I originally figured it out based on the manifest.. if things are going strangely for you, try having VS generate an external manifest and comparing the CRT version it asks for with the CRT version installed under C:\windows .. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

You need a template argument:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Test> t1(new Test);
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Test> t2 = t1->shared_from_this();
```

The compiler should report an error if it is not present. (Visual C++ 2010 does)

Comment: The program is fine and t1 instance is getting created until I add the next line where I try to call shared_from_this() this is when the program crashes with the mentioned error.

Comment: Ok, could you check what version of MSVCP90D.dll is being used when you run the app? (using depends.exe)
I have version 9.0.30729.1 and that one includes the procedure entry point ?_Xweak@tr1@std@@YAXXZ.

Comment: MSVCP90D.dll version loaded when it crashed 9.0.21022.8. Dependency walker complained about this **Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.**

Comment: @John M: you should be able to see where that happens.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your compiler is not linking against a DLL with the needed runtime functions.  For instance, if you added the headers to your include path, but don't link to the latest version of the C++ runtime (check your project's settings), or installing [the Visual C++ 2008 feature pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en) didn't work, or you installed the feature pack but then tried to compile from Visual Studio 2005, etc.

Basically the "process the source code (including headers)" step is working fine, but the "link all the DLLs" step is failing.  And it's failing because the runtime you're linking against doesn't have the needed functions for `shared_ptr`s or `weak_ptr`s.

Comment: Ok what are the lib files I need to link for the smart pointer to work

Comment: shared pointer and enable_shared_from_this doesn't need the Visual Studio C++ 2008 feature pack since they are already defined in Technology Review TR1 namespace. I have not installed the feature pack. The problem with the code is in line where I call shared_from_this(). Apart from that whole program executes fine.

Comment: They are defined in TR1, but Visual Studio 2008 **did not ship with TR1**.  Not only do you need to install the feature pack on your computer, but you also have to install a redistributable on all computers you want to run the program on.  I work at a company that does exactly that.  Plus, you'll see on the page that I linked to that "This feature pack also includes an implementation of TR1. ... Our implementation includes a number of important features such as ... Smart pointers."  Hint:  the feature pack **exists** because TR1 is not part of 2008 base install.

Comment: I don't know which lib files you need, but they are part of the feature pack.  Another possibility is that you somehow got the feature pack installed, had the include files added to the include path but did not get the DLLs added to the linker path.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when developing under M$ Windows SP3 with M$ Visual Studio 2008. I tried and combined many hints that I could find on the web. To no avail. The solution was simple, I had to install SP1 pack for M$ Visual Studio 2008!

The thing is that my external DLLs used C++ TR1 functions that I was not aware of. The M$ Visual Studio 2008 without SP does not have the right runtime DLLs.

So, just make sure you have that SP1 for your M$ Visual Studio 2008 first before trying any other solution.